# Is there a control in windows phone 8.0 that will show the redirect url

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have URL which on redirect should return a another URL that contains either "success" or "error", but be it webbrowser control or webtask, neither gives the return URL. Is there a control in windows phone 8.0 that can help in achieving this.

I know that in 8.1 we have a webview control in which it works like a charm, but my project is built in 8.0 using VS2012. And to convert it into an 8.1 using VS2013 will be a very time consuming task for the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebBrowser control in windows phone 8.0 works exactly like the IE. Similarly to IE, you need to enable scripting in the WebBrowser control by writing the following code in the xaml

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="myBrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

Or you can do the same by going to properties and checking the `IsScriptEnabled` property to true.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the HttpClient?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.yahoo.com/");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseUri = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Dimitris, We have that as part of the code, but need the response as part of the flow as the next action depends on the output of the URL. Also, we are showing the URL response to the user. Hence, we want to use WebBrowser control. Luckily we found out the solution for the issue. It works exactly like the IE. Similarly to IE, you need to enable scripting in the WebBrowser control by writing the following code in the xaml
<phone:WebBrowser Name=”myBrowser” IsScriptEnabled=”True” />
Or you can do the same by going to properties and checking the IsScriptEnabled property to true.